# Sql Developer is not able to connect to oracle database instance running in docker container

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerfile, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Attaching the screenshot of the error that I am recieving** while trying to connect to oracle database instance in which is inside docker container[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reasons may be many hopefully your oracle database must be running on ur local host and listener service up and running to listen requests.

Please check both are running then you should be able to connect easily.

Comment: oracle database is in docker container, the container is running but still sqldeveloper is not able to connect to the database instance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you bind the container port to the HostOS.

```
# we bind host_os_port:to_container_port
docker container run -d -p 1521:1521 --name oracle23c -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=Welcome_#1 gvenzl/oracle-free:full-faststart

# verify
sudo lsof -i :1521
COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 1164 BJBRA  212u  IPv6 0xdaaecd52ca51aa41      0t0  TCP *:ncube-lm (LISTEN)

#login with sqlplus
export TWO_TASK=localhost/FREEPDB1
echo "select sysdate;" | sqlplus -S sys/Welcome_#1 as sysdba

SYSDATE
-------------------
10.07.2023 06:27:34
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the alert of the oracle to check whether your database is up and running.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).